# Restoring NSArray from file

Tags: objective-c, file, encryption, nsarray, nsdata

I have an array that I serialize, encrypt and then write into a file. The data itself appears to be good but I'm having problems restoring the array back from the file. Here is what I do

```
    NSString *filename = [[self getTransactionLogPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:transactionLogName];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];
    NSLog(@"encrypted data: %@", data);
    EncryptedData *decoder = [[EncryptedData alloc] init];
    NSData *decrypted = [decoder reverseTransformedValue:data];
    NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decrypted];
```

I get the filename and read the data from file. EncryptedData decoder runs AES128 on the data and finally I unarchive the array.

The problem is that unarchiveObjectWithData throws an exception

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]:
```

incomprehensible archive

The tricky thing is that the code works fine in simulator if I keep the NSLog line i.e. I print out the data after reading the file.

On device the `NSLog()` does not help. Is this a threading problem where the unarchiver starts before the data is read?

I tried adding a delay instead of the NSLog() line but that didn't help.

Any other ways to do the job if I want to encrypt the array before writing to file?

Comment: What does `[self getTransactionLogPath]` return?

Comment: Can you share the code where you actually serialze, save and encrypt the array?

Comment: Here is the writing part. As I said the code works as long as I have the NSLog() line so the data should be good. filename in the code has the right path and file name. NSData *serialized = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array]];
    EncryptedData *coder = [[EncryptedData alloc] init];
    NSData *encrypted = [coder transformedValue:serialized];
    NSString *filename = [[self getTransactionLogPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:transactionLogName];
    [encrypted writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];

Comment: [self getTransactionLogPath] returns a path to the directory where the file is

Comment: NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask

Comment: Have you compared the NSData that you encrypt with the NSData you end up with after decrypting?  Are they byte-for-byte identical?  Also, do you have the same bug if you leave out the encrypt/decrypt steps?

Comment: @Avi, I have printed out the data and the decrypted data is identical to the data that I encrypt. However, when I removed the encryption/decryption and just write and read the serialized NSArray the code works without errors. So, you're right, it has to do with my decryption call but how can it be dependent on the NSLog() line?

Comment: The NSLog() changes the timing.  My guess is a race condition.  Is it at all possible that some part of the decryption is asynchronous?